# Looping through divs with a numerically ordered id names?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs with id names type1, type2, type3 and type4. I need help with some sort of jquery that gives a green background to the 1st div and then after 2 seconds the next div gets a green background and the first one goes back to the normal background color and so on. I need the looping to go on forever.

```
<div id="type1">
<p>Hey</p>
</div>

<div id="type2">
<p>Hello></p>
</div>

<div id="type3">
<p>Hey again</p>
</div>

<div id="type4">
<p>Hello again</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What part of your code isn't working properly? `id`s with the same prefix should probably be classes.

Comment: Could you just do it via the display order, or is the id order different?  Will there ever be more than 10 IDs?

Comment: ok, lets say that i used classes instead and named all of the divs to class "type". How could i use jquery to loop through them?

Comment: I would suggest adding classes, then you could get an array of elements with that class. I think what others are asking is that you at least show some effort first at doing what you ask.

Comment: @BrianHoover No, I can't do it by display order, unfortunately. There will not be more than 10 ids.

Comment: @crush This is actually a simplified version, I am trying to iterate through the divs. I have used classes before but it didnt work because type1 and typ2 are together but in a seperate parent div than type3, and type4. hence, i can't seem to cycle through with classes adn so i decided to use IDs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I'd like to point out that this can be done without Javascript

using `css animations`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/YngTH/3/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="animated"></div>
<div>
<p>Hey</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Hello></p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Hey again</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Hello again</p>
</div>
```

### (Relevant) CSS

```
.animated
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background:green;
    z-index:-1;
    animation: move 8s steps(4) infinite;    
}

@keyframes move {
  from { top: 0; }
  to   { top: 400px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a class name on the DIVs, say "type" and have less than 10 DIVS, this will work.  This will work in other cases too, but you would need to do a little modification to the sort routine.

```
orderDivs = $(".type").sort(asc_sort);
//$("#debug").text("Output:");
// accending sort
function asc_sort(a, b){
    return ($(b).attr('id')) < ($(a).attr('id')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
var divSize = orderDivs.length;
var currentDiv = divSize -1;
var lastDiv = orderDivs[divSize-1];
console.log(orderDivs[0]);
function highLightNext() {
    $(lastDiv).css('background-color','transparent');
    currentDiv = (currentDiv+1) % divSize;
    lastDiv = orderDivs[currentDiv]; 
    $(lastDiv).css('background-color','green');
    setTimeout(highLightNext,1000);
}

highLightNext();
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57hXh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JQuery, there's plenty of way to do this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KnjED/1/

**EDIT:** 
This doesn't loop infinitely (Didn't read the description properly)
Working on fixing that :)

HTML:

```
<div class="type">
<p>Hey</p>
</div>

<div class="type">
<p>Hello></p>
</div>

<div class="type">
<p>Hey again</p>
</div>

<div class="type">
<p>Hello again</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    background: green;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".type").each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay(2000*i).queue(function() { 
       $(this).addClass('green');
         $(this).prev().removeClass('green');
    })
});
```